# Objectify - com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving : id cannot be zero

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I got the following error in a Google App Engine project that utilizes Objectify:

```
[INFO] com.googlecode.objectify.SaveException: Error saving com.netbase.model.InsightDataSet@13b24628: id cannot be zero
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.EntityMetadata.save(EntityMetadata.java:95)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.WriteEngine.save(WriteEngine.java:73)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entities(SaverImpl.java:60)
[INFO]  at com.googlecode.objectify.impl.SaverImpl.entity(SaverImpl.java:35)
[INFO]  at com.netbase.server.InsightManager.persistInsights(InsightManager.java:26)
[INFO]  at com.netbase.server.LongTestServlet.downloadAllInsightsAsTimeSeriesAndSend(LongTestServlet.java:140)
[INFO]  at com.netbase.server.LongTestServlet.doHelper(LongTestServlet.java:98)
[INFO]  at com.netbase.server.LongTestServlet.doPost(LongTestServlet.java:52)
```

Here is how my java class is defined:

```
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
public class InsightDataSet {
    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id long id;
```

Here is how I'm trying to save it:

```
    InsightDataSet insightDataSet = new InsightDataSet(username, topicId, requestDate);
    ofy().save().entity(insightDataSet).now();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/aRRRQNILQb0 the field tagged with the Objectify annotation @Id needs to be `Long` instead of `long` in order for Objectify to auto-generate the Java object's id.

So I changed my class definition to:

```
@com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Entity
public class InsightDataSet {
    @com.googlecode.objectify.annotation.Id Long id;
```

This fixed the problem.